# Add directory to existing git repo without subproject?

Tags: git

I'm trying to put together a pull request for an existing git repos.  I've forked the project and cloned it to my system.  When I add a directory to the existing project and then try to "git add --all *" or pretty much anything else to add this new directory full of files.

Every time I do this, it tries to add it as a subproject.  **I don't want that!** I want this directory to be just a normal part of the original git project so that I can then provide a pull request and the owner can see all of the guts of this new directory as if it were a full member of the project.

I've googled about this, but everything I found seemed to suggest you have to actually work at it to make it turn into a submodule/subproject.  For me it is happening automatically (and frustratingly).

Comment: "git repos" How many repos are you dealing with?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [repo](https://code.google.com/p/git-repo/), which helps you to manage multi git repos.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the subdirectory is already a git repo. If you just want to add the files to the parent repo, you can delete the .git directory from the subdirectory before adding it.

Comment: Thanks all, I got it solved. It turns out it WAS kind of the "left over .git directory inside directory", but not exactly. I had actually thought of that somewhere along the way and removed it...but git is like an elephant. It never forgets!

I ultimately had to change the name of the directory and make sure there was no .git dir inside of it...and then it finally worked right after that. I was able to "git add --all foo-dir" and add all of its contents into the main git repo.

thanks for all the help!