# Cannot add directory to git repo

Tags: git, github

I have a git repository at `repo` on my local computer, and on GitHub I have a repo `online` with main branches `main` and `b2`.  On my local computer I have branches `master` and `b2`.  The local `repo` directory has subdirectory `repo\subdir`.  On GitHub this subdirectory is not showing up in `online` branch `b2` (or any other branch, but it will be victory if I can get it on `b2`).

Now when I pull up a Powershell pointed to `repo` and enter `git checkout b2` it says that I'm on branch `b2`.  I run `git add .` and it gives no error messages.  If I enter `git status` it says that nothing is untracked.  I commit and it says the branch is clean, nothing to commit.  I push with `git push -u origin b2` it says

```
Everything up-to-date
branch 'b2' set up to track 'origin/b2'.
```

Everything looks as good as I can imagine!

I go to the GitHub page, and everything else in the repo is there, except for `subdir`.  No branch, including `b2`, contains `subdir`.  I go to `Pull Requests`, set it to `main <- b2` and it says there are no differences.

---

This seems like, whatever this is, I'd expect it to be common.  But when I search for other people with the problem, I don't see anything that looks applicable.  These are my nearest search results:

[Unable to add a directory to git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22469174/unable-to-add-a-directory-to-git-repo)

[Add directory to existing git repo without subproject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22029765/add-directory-to-existing-git-repo-without-subproject)

And I continually asked ChatGPT what to do and I seem to have exhausted all of its ideas.

Comment: Is there anything _in_ that subdirectory?

Comment: @tkausl there are further subdirectories which are all empty.  However, I'm only just realizing that they're empty -- they were supposed to have many files, all of which are missing now.  Luckily I had them backed up elsewhere and I'm adding them back in now.  Will report an update soon.

Comment: @tkausl Ah well, whatever that was, it was the issue!  I don't know how the files went missing, but when I add them back in then everything is fine now!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git does **not** track folders, it tracks *files*.

Your folders probably contain no files, therefore git has nothing to track.

Some people work around this issue by adding a 0-byte file called `.gitkeep` to each folder that they want to keep in the repository, even if empty.